# MWI universal wave function question?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations

In MWI, there is only one wave function in the universe ( the universal wave function). So say if I detected a particle and its wave function decoheres, since the universal wave function never collapses are there other parts of the universe that can still interfere? 
Is this a stupid question?

Answer (score 1):

> In MWI, there is only one wave function in the universe ( the universal wave function). So say if I detected a particle and its wave function decoheres, since the universal wave function never collapses are there other parts of the universe that can still interfere? Is this a stupid question?

Your question is not stupid.

In the MWI, information spreads locally. So if system A in region 1 decoheres, system B in region 2 may still undergo interference.

More broadly, parallel universes are an approximation in the MWI that breaks down in interference experiments and sometimes also for macroscopic systems. See 'The Beginning of Infinity' and 'The Fabric of Reality' by David Deutsch for popular accounts and for more technical accounts see

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0107144

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

Comment: Ok, so according to MWI, say if I had an *entangled* pair of photons. I detect the position of photon 1 and it decoheres into different position states. What happens to photon 2? Does that photon also decohere as well or no?

Comment: If photons 1 and 2 have entangled positions, then they can't exhibit interference wrt position. However, if you measure photon 1's position and it is separated from photon 2, that measurement has no effect on photon 2. So photon 2 is not decohered by anything you do to photon 1. However, photon 1 may have locally inaccessible information about photon 2 that could in principle be returned to photon 2 which would allow photon 2 to undergo interference wrt position. Once you have measured photon 1 you can no longer do that experiment. Technical acccount https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

Comment: What do you mean by entangled positions? What if they are shot off into different directions?

Comment: how about this article, do the photons here have entangled positions?

Comment: http://www.pnas.org/content/109/24/9314.full

Comment: You could have two photons that entangled in their polarisations but not in positions. I think that the photons are entangled in position in the paper you link.

Comment: So when the idle photon position is detected and it decoheres, does the signal photon decohere as well?

Comment: The effects of decoherence spread locally, so one of the photon's decohering doesn't affect the other until information spreads from one to the other.

Comment: So is that why the signal can still produce interference when the idle is detected?

Comment: Keep in mind that while the two photons do have entangled positions, they are separated. And you said that when the entangled position photons go in separate directions a measurement on one should have no effect on the other

Comment: Are you claiming it makes a difference whether the idler is detected and if so what are you claiming the difference is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54780/discussion-between-2117-and-alanf).